# Getting longitude and latidude from postgis database with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, function, sqlalchemy, postgis, latitude-longitude

I am using the sqlalchemy package to state queries to my postgis database which is filled with .osm data of a city. I want to retrieve the longitude and latitude values from lets say the planet_osm_point table. 
I state the sql query which looks like this:

```
      SELECT st_y(st_asewkt(st_transform(way, 4326))) as lat,
             st_x(st_asewkt(st_transform(way, 4326))) as lon
             "addr:housenumber" AS husenumber,
             "addr:street" AS street,
             "addr:postcode" AS postcode
      FROM planet_osm_point
```

Sqlalchemy throws me this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (psycopg2.InternalError) FEHLER:  Argument to ST_Y() must be a point
```

The only problem is the **ST_Y()** and **ST_X()** function.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ST_X/ST_Y` Return floats. You could either use the floats or cast them to text.

Using `ST_AsEWKT` is problematic here since both `ST_Y/ST_X` return `floats` and `ST_AsEWKT` expects a `geometry`.

Use the floats you get:

```
SELECT st_y(st_transform(way, 4326)) AS lat,
             st_x(st_transform(way, 4326)) AS lon
             "addr:housenumber" AS husenumber,
             "addr:street" AS street,
             "addr:postcode" AS postcode
      FROM planet_osm_point
```

Or cast to text:

```
SELECT cast(st_y(st_transform(way, 4326)) as text) AS lat,
             cast(st_x(st_transform(way, 4326)) as text) AS lon
             "addr:housenumber" AS husenumber,
             "addr:street" AS street,
             "addr:postcode" AS postcode
      FROM planet_osm_point
```

Comment: Hmm, but according to the postgis reference it is indeed called asewkt and there is no function aswkt:
[ST_AsEWKT](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_AsEWKT.html)
[Postgis functions](http://www.postgis.net/docs/)

Comment: [`ST_Y`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Y.html) and [`ST_X`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_X.html) return the y and x coordinate of a point as a float, respectively. [`ST_AsEWKT`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_AsEWKT.html) expects a geometry as the argument. That'd seem like a bad match.

Comment: Okay, I tried it this way but I still get the error that the argument to ST_Y must be a point.

Comment: Or, don't use anything at all, since the floating point value is the coordinate value.

Comment: Modified answer to include both solutions, either use the floats as ilja mentions or cast to text.

Comment: Okay feeling kind of dumb now. I did not try it with the planet_osm_point, I instead used the planet_osm_polygon table. Where the geometry type objects obviously do not consist of only one point. But either way thanks for trying to help me :)

Comment: Glad we could help, if you dont mind, please mark the answer as correct :)